# Find a character and then insert HTML tag before it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some text that display using this markup that I can't change unfortunately

```
<a class="bt" href="#url">Leadership in Education (29 Oct - 31 Oct 2014)</a>
```

I'd like to append a `<br />` just before the ( so that the date would display on a new line

How do I go about of doing this?

Here's what I've been trying but with no idea how to execute what I'd like to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/w6gp2af3/

Comment: Why not just do this in the html before-hand?

Comment: @tcooc I wish I could :( but can't be changed as it's fixed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("a:contains('(')").html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace(" (", "<br />("); 
});
```

```js
$("a:contains('(')").html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace(" (", "<br />("); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="bt-title-nointro" target="_parent" title="Leadership in Health Professions Education (29 Sep - 3 Oct 2014)" href="/index.php/component/content/article/54-main-banner/66-leadership-in-health-professions-education-transformational-leadership-to-inspire-change">
                                       Leadership in Health Professions Education (29 Sep - 3 Oct 2014)                                  </a>
```

Comment: I never thought of using a function to return content for `.html()`. That's GENIUS. I've been doing it the ugly way, like `.html( .html() )` all this time. +1 for the unintended tip!

Comment: MasyaAllah that is a SUPER cool answer. I knew I didn't have to do a regex. Wow, SUPER cool, really!!!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selects DOM elements. A bunch of text is not a DOM element, therefore you need to treat it like a string and use string.replace (or regex) to insert the BR where you want it.

You can use jQuery to select the wrapping element. The rest is string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. You gave me the theory and @j08691 gave me the answer hehe

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do this for every `a` element on your page, so I suggest you add a selector to the code below where appropriate.

The following code uses your selector, and replaces `(` with `<br>(`. Very simple.

```
$( "a:contains('(')" ).each(function() {
    jQuery(this).html( jQuery(this).html().replace('(', '<br>(') );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code and thanks for the reminder! I'll add a selector before the a

Comment: I'd suggest you use @j08691's answer (if you didn't already). It's less redundant, but achieves the same goal. I'll leave my answer just for the added suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to replace the open paren with a `<br/>(`.  See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/w6gp2af3/2/

Answer (score 1):

Quick and Easy (this will work for all anchors on your page, so long as they only have one open parenthesis each...):

```
$( "a:contains('(')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" ).each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("(","<br/>("));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hajx6ffz/